# android layout?

Tags: android, layout, tablelayout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android - layout - Resize ImageButtons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391532/android-layout-resize-imagebuttons)

For example: How can i make a 10 x 10 Table Layout (100% horizontal and 100% vertical). And e.g. in row 2 and column 2 is a button. The button should fill the area.

I searched so long, too many peoples have problems with layouts.

Comment: Not duplicate. Its my question. When somebody has a Soultion for the old post, than its good for me. But in this question I'm asking for the 10 x 10 Table layout.

Comment: in that case you should re-write this question to make it clearer.

Comment: `I searched so long, too many peoples have problems with layouts.`. Then there might be too many different kind of problems, how can we know what your problem is **exactly**?

Comment: You can use square layout (Custom layout which heigh is same as width). 

(i.) Use root LinearLayout with `orientation=vertical`.

(ii.) Now again use LinearLayout (for row) with `orientation=horizontal`. 

(iii.) In that layout add square layout for ten times.

(iv.) Repeat -ii and -iii step 9 times more.

Now Result will be 10x10 grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a LinearLayout with `layout_width=fill_parent`, `layout_height=fill_parent`, and `orientation=vertical`.

Inside it, create 10 LinearLayouts with `layout_width=fill_parent`, `layout_height=0dp`, `layout_weight=1`, and `orientation=horizontal`.

Inside each of these 10 LinearLayouts, create your views (whatever your views are -i.e. Buttons or whatever) with `layout_width=0dp`, `layout_height=fill_parent`, and `layout_weight=1`.

Comment: no, nothing works. you tried that. This works?